# Angular - Manually set a form as Submitted

Tags: angular, forms

In order to submit an angular form, you need to have a button of type `submit` within your form and to click on it. That will mark the form as submitted.

But what is for whatever reason, we want to Manually mark the form as submitted form the typescript code, is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way but it's a bit hacky

In your form create a button (hide it from the DOM if needed) like this

```html
    <form [formGroup]="textboxForm" #myForm="ngForm">
      ... Whatever you want inside your form
      <button #myButton type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </form>
```

And in the typescript code

```js
  @ViewChild('myButton', { read: ElementRef }) public myButton!: ElementRef;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myButton.nativeElement.click();
  }
```

Here I am simulating the user clicking on the `submit` button from my form. I could not find a `markAsSubmitted()` method similar to `markAsDirty()`